# Why is my python find() function finding more values than in the string?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
tempStorage = 'GOOD.LUCK'
print(tempStorage.find("."))
```

Instead of outputting 1, it outputs 4. Can someone tell me why?

Edit - I'm stupid, I confused `count()` with `find()`

Comment: The find method returns index. For more information, you can refer to docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Comment: I recommend getting into the habit of checking the docstring either online or via the REPL with `help(str.find)`. Having done that you'd have seen that `str.find` returns the index of the first occurrence of the target string in the calling string. Then you might try `dir(str)` to get a list of all the methods supported by the `str` type, and then you might've seen `str.count`. Try to get into this workflow, it'll save you a lot of time and headaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) which tells you the position.

You should use [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) instead which counts the number of occurrences.

```
tempStorage = 'GOOD.LUCK'
print(tempStorage.count("."))
>>> 1
```

Comment: @Lucas Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm glad I could help. If my solution has solved your problem, please be free to click the checkmark next to it and [accept it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). This lets other users know that your question was solved and awards us both a reputation bonus.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method in Python returns the index of where the first match is. In your case, the period was in index 4.

Answer (score 0):

Python find() method returns an index

Definition and Usage
The find() method finds the first occurrence of the specified value.

The find() method returns -1 if the value is not found.

The find() method is almost the same as the index() method, the only difference is that the index() method raises an exception if the value is not found.

Like the answer above says, you should use the count() method to get the answer you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

This method returns the index of the first occurence of a letter in a  string, for example.

```
str = "My name is python"
print(str.find("i"))
```

Since the counting always starts at zero, the output will be 8
plus

```
print(str.find("is"))
```

Also returns 8, which is the index of the first character in a string given in the parameter